# Nginx global config inherits from named config?

Tags: nginx, configuration

I've got two nginx configs, one is a global catchall config without a server name set that should handle any request. And i got a second configuration that has a server name set that handles only the requests on a specific subdomain.

Examples (not real config but there isn't much more there at all):

```
server {
 listen 80;
 root /www/live;

 location
 ....
}

server {
 listen 80;
 server_name *.prelive.host.tld;
 root /www/prelive;

 auth_basic "Restricted";
 auth_basic_user_file /etc/htpasswd;

 location
 ....
}
```

But when I include the second one into the configuration the whole page goes password protected, not only prelive pages.

Any ideas what could cause the first config to inherit the basic auth?

Comment: Probably a typo, bad paste, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like nginx will "randomly" select one of the configurations as the default configuration in the mentioned setup. Our solution was to set

```
listen 80 default_server;
```

instead of

```
listen 80;
```

on the default config so nginx would always choose that configuration for anything except matched server names.